# How i can get content of a file of privios directory

Tags: php

i am using `show.php` to get content of a file. The `show.php` file's location is:
    /home/u745573307/public_html/user/profile/show.php

i want to get contant of a file from previous directory like:

```
 /home/u745573307/public_html/user/edit.php
```

i am using this tag:

```
$file = file_get_contents ('../edit.php' , true);
```

what is the correct tag?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is quite good, provided that your include path includes ".".

If it does not, or you want to ensure that you go one directory up for other reasons, you could use this approach:

```
$file = file_get_contents(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . 'edit.php');
```

[dirname()](http://php.net/dirname) gives you the directory name of the file path you specified.

***IF*** you are using PHP7 already, you can also shorten that by using the newly introduced `$level` parameter, like so:

```
$file = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__, 2) . 'edit.php');
```